# How to get post meta for custom post type and taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, post-meta

I am trying to access post meta for custom post type and taxonomy using WP_Query and then query the posts with that specific post meta.

So far I have tied the following code:

```
$hot_args = array(
                            'post_type' => 'video',
                            'posts_per_page' => '6',
                            "order" => "DESC",
                            'meta_key' => 'post_views_count',
                            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
                            'date_query'  => array(
                                array(
                                    'after' => '1 week ago'
                                )
                            ),
                            "post__not_in" => $posts__not_in,
                            'tax_query' => array(
                                array(
                                    'taxonomy' => 'video_cat',
                                    'field' => 'slug',
                                    'terms' => "all"
                                )
                            ),
                        );
                        $hot_query = new WP_Query( $hot_args );
```

This code doesn't work and not returning any results.
For normal posts this piece of code works but for custom post type doesn't, How can I make it work for custom post types?

Answer (score 0):

Find The problem ;)
The answer is

```
$hot_args = array(
                            'post_type' => 'video',
                            'posts_per_page' => '6',
                            "order" => "DESC",
                            'meta_key' => 'post_views_count',
                            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
                            'date_query'  => array(
                                array(
                                    'after' => '1 week ago'
                                )
                            ),
                            "post__not_in" => $posts__not_in,
                        );
                        $hot_query = new WP_Query( $hot_args );
```

There was not video as my custom post type exists in the past week so the there was nothing to return :)

Answer (score 0):

You should not use post meta in your case. This will result in slow database query performance. Use a custom table instead.

Have a look at one of these:

- [Would this post meta be better added to the post table rather than post_meta table](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/258752/would-this-post-meta-be-better-added-to-the-post-table-rather-than-post-meta-tab/388111#388111)