# Would this post meta be better added to the post table rather than post_meta table

Tags: wp-query, post-meta, mysql

I have a function that records the post views, and my post loops can be ordered by post views. This is the code:

```
/**
 * Set Post views
 *
 */
function hp_global_set_post_views() {
    if (!is_single()) 
        return;

    global $post;
    $post_id = $post->ID;    

    $view_count = get_post_meta($post_id, 'view_count', true);
    $view_count++;
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'view_count', $view_count);
}
add_action('wp_head', 'hp_global_set_post_views');

/** example query args to order posts by veiw count */
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$query_args = array(
    'paged'    => $paged,
    'orderby'  => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'    => 'DESC',
    'meta_key' => 'view_count'
);
```

If you have a website with large traffic, would it be better to create a new column in the _posts table called 'view_count' and then update that column everytime a post gets a view instead of creating a new row for each post in the post meta?

And the QP_QUERY args can be written like:

```
// args to Order posts by veiw count
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$query_args = array(
    'paged'    => $paged,
    'orderby'  => 'view_count',
    'order'    => 'DESC'
);
```

I'm really unsure of the best way to structure a database for a website for the best performance. Why would this be a good idea or bad idea. Any help appreciated.